# Terminal font broken after exiting vim

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh

My terminal's (alacrity with zsh/powerlevel10k) font breaks after I leave vim.

Anyone that could tell me how I could fix this?

[image: Broken terminal font]

Interestingly, the font seems to fix itself if I enter and then exit vim again.

Comment: I find your problem interesting, but I have to vote for a close, because such questions belong to i.e. [su]. May I suggest that you ask it there again, and also provide information about which OS you are using, which terminal emulator, and which vim version.

Comment: Thank you, reposted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1652883/terminal-font-breaks-after-exiting-vim)! How do I close my question here?

Comment: If you see the "close" link here, you can choose it, but this just *votes* for closing. 3 votes are needed to close a question. If you don't see the close link, it means that you don't have yet enough reputation at [so]. In this case you can simply leave it as it is and wait until it gets reaped by the moderators. Alternatively you can delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update vim to latest version

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
$ cd vim/src
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Still breaks it